# Sql query returns empty value, but in list have some values in java

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, repository

I was trying to query the table which returns an empty value in DB. And after I am setting it in List but while checking the list it was not empty. Why it was not empty or null? But DB returns empty only for the query.

Example:
List keyLook = Repository.getTypeFromTable(key);
Repository query is
@Query(value = "SELECT TYPE FROM KEY_LOOK WHERE KEY IN (:KEY)", nativeQuery = true)

While query in DB, returns as attached image. But while checking keyLook list it is not empty. Due to this, it is skipping null or empty check in Java, and the loop move inside implementations. what is the cause of this issue?

[image]